# Prevent implementation of interface, allow interfaces exteding base interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Let there be:

```
public interface BaseInterface {}
```

and:

```
public interface SubInterfaceA {}
public interface SubInterfaceB {}
```

Is there any way in Java to prevent creation of classes (any, abstract, concrete, anonymous) directly implementing BaseInterface without implementing SubInterfaceA or SubInterfaceB? Unfortunately simply writing

```
public abstract interface BaseInterface {}
```

does not work - for (obvious?) reasons.

I need my classes to implement tag interfaces, each interface with its own inheritance hierarchy. Let's think "Serializable" with "JSONSerializable" and "XMLSerializable", where "Serializable" is not enough to serialize object - I know that this particular case can be (and was) solved differently, but in my case it is not that easy.

Comment: You could put them inside a package and make `BaseInterface` package-private. But perhaps you'd probably lose the benefit of `BaseInterface` existing at all. You're probably better off just putting comments on it explaining how it should be used.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, unfortunately these interfaces must be visible outside of their package - there is a module (in different package) keeping references to objects via these interfaces, also other packages must be able to check if object has this type.

Comment: Option B then: document your interface explaining how it should be used, and trust other developers.

Comment: Well, this is what I'm going to do if there is no other option to do what I want in less... "procedural" way. It's just that I thought that there is some readily available solution - preferably via language constructs, then using compiler extension and in the end... I don't know, by extending ClassLoader?

Comment: In short, no. I want to challenge your design: if `Serializable` is not enough to serialize object why does it exist ? Why do you want to solve that differently than how it is solved in general ? Can you provide more concrete examples so that one can help you to better design this "tag" functionality ?

Comment: "In short, no" - thanks, that's what I thought. Regarding "Serializable" - it was just to clarify what I want to achieve and I explicitly wrote, that its not the best one, so there's nothing to challenge.

Comment: And now I see that this question was already answered. Honestly whenever I ask a question I try as hard as I can to find an answer since it is easier than asking a good question, then I can't find it so I write a question, and then bam!, 5 minutes and someone marks it as "duplicate", and rightly so.

Comment: If your question is marked as duplicate, you don't need to be offended, it's just that us, programmers, hate redundancy. However, if you take time to explain properly your problem (with concrete examples) and show us which solutions you already tried, then and only then your question will be so specific than nobody will be able to find a duplicate ever.

Comment: @Spotted No no, don't take me wrong, I'm not offended that it is marked as a duplicate, I'm annoyed with myself unable to find previous answer on my own. I'm absolutely fine with marking my question as duplicates if they are really duplicates - and in this case it obviously is.